# How to join two tables matching for unique column ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my code below.

```
select cserv.cust_id,serv.service_id,serv.service_name,cserv.cust_id,cserv.channel_id,cserv2.cust_id,cserv2.channel_id
from services as serv
left join cust_services as cserv on serv.channel_a=cserv.channel_id
left join cust_services as cserv2 on serv.channel_b=cserv2.channel_id
where cserv.cust_id IS NOT NULL
order by cserv.cust_id
```

and below is picture of my result which generates by this query.

[image]

and below is the image of issue. issue is marked with red color.

[image]

I want to remove the highlighted record . How can i do that? Please help me.

below is the pictures of my service table and cust_service tables.

service table :-

[image]

cust_service :-

[image]

Comment: Please clarify by which criterion you want to remove row from results? Do you want: cserv.cust_id = cserv2.cust_id  ?

Comment: yes. thats the thing

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this with your data sets and it appears to provide the output you are looking for:

```
SELECT MIN(cserv.cust_id) AS cust_id1
      ,MIN(serv.service_id) AS service_id
      ,serv.service_name
      ,MIN(cserv.cust_id) AS cust_id2
      ,MIN(cserv.channel_id) AS channel_id
      ,cserv2.cust_id
      ,cserv2.channel_id
FROM services as serv
    LEFT JOIN cust_services AS cserv ON serv.channel_a=cserv.channel_id
    LEFT JOIN cust_services AS cserv2 ON serv.channel_b=cserv2.channel_id
WHERE cserv.cust_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY serv.service_name
        ,cserv2.cust_id
        ,cserv2.channel_id
ORDER BY cust_id1, service_id
```

Here is the sqlfiddle of the OP and my answer with respective outputs: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74bc16/2

Notice, I changed the name of `cust_id` fields because they were causing a field ambiguous error since they were both named the same thing.  Now they are labeled `cust_id1` and `cust_id2` so you can do order and sorting by them.  I also added `service_id` in the `ORDER BY` clause so the order in your original example is retained; you may choose to order by something else.

Comment: I'm making a sample data set with your examples now to test. give me a few minutes...

Comment: I've tested this and it appears to work.  Let me know if it helps and can be used in your implementation.  We can work on another solution if it does not work.